# Core NFC convert identifier Data into String

Tags: swift, core-nfc

With the recent Core NFC updates you can now access the identifier from a miFare Tag.

This identifier is of type Data. How do you convert this data into its string value?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the origin of `Data`, you can convert `Data` into `String` by using `String(data: Data, encoding: String.Encoding)`. As for encoding, it would most likely be `UTF8`. So you can do something like this

```
let identifierData: Data = //identifier data
let stringValue = String(data: identifierData, encoding: .utf8)
```